# Repeating data validation

Tags: java

I need to ask three levels of pay. Level 1 must be at least 65k, level 2 must be at least 60k. Level 1 must also be at least 110% of level 2. Level 2 must also be at least 120% of level 3. I'm only starting with level 1 and 2 since if I can figure that out, I can figure out level 3. Here's what I have:

```
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter the full time employee payscale level 1 rate: ");
        fullTimePay1 = input.nextInt();
    } while (fullTimePay1 < 65000);

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter the full time employee payscale level 2 rate: ");
        fullTimePay2 = input.nextInt();
        } while (fullTimePay2 < 60000);

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter the full time employee payscale level 1 rate: ");
        fullTimePay1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the full time employee payscale level 2 rate: ");
        fullTimePay2 = input.nextInt();
    } while (fullTimePay1 < (fullTimePay2 * 1.1));
```

But it just repeats over and over (I have a print statement after this code that never executes). Can anyone tell me why and maybe help with my code?

Comment: I would step through your code in a debugger so you understand what your program is doing.  I would have thought you want only one loop and you don't want to ask again once you have the right answer.

Comment: What is input and where does the next int come from ? Why are you repeatedly getting the next int ?

Comment: This isn't my entire code, just the part that won't work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code stands, when I enter e.g. 100000 and 70000 (twice) the loop terminates; were you maybe confusing which value should be bigger (or not trying more than once in a row)?

Your code will not work correctly because you're not doing the 65k and 60k validation on your third loop and you're also asking for each input twice rather than just once (when entered correctly) (do-while checks the condition **after** the loop, rather than before (which a while-loop would do), so the third loop will ask for user input regardless of what the values were).

Replacing the 3 loops with the below should work:

```
do {
  do {
    System.out.println("Please enter full time employee payscale level 1 rate:");
    fullTimePay1 = input.nextInt();
  } while (fullTimePay1 < 65000);
  do {
    System.out.println("Please enter full time employee payscale level 2 rate:");
    fullTimePay2 = input.nextInt();
  } while (fullTimePay2 < 60000);
} while (fullTimePay1 < (fullTimePay2 * 1.1));
```

But validating the 110% on the second one only would make more sense to me, if this is allowed:

```
do {
  System.out.println("Please enter full time employee payscale level 1 rate:");
  fullTimePay1 = input.nextInt();
} while (fullTimePay1 < 66000); // 'cause min(1) = 1.1*min(2) = 1.1*60000 = 66000
do {
  System.out.println("Please enter full time employee payscale level 2 rate:");
  fullTimePay2 = input.nextInt();
} while (fullTimePay2 < 60000 || fullTimePay1 < (fullTimePay2 * 1.1));
```